# Add Devices to Provisionning Profile?

Tags: iphone, provisioning, device

My Devices tab on developper.apple.com is missing the Add new Device or Buld upload buttons ?

Am I missing something, these buttons used to be there ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you  [pre-release Apple Software](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381570/932011)

Comment: So this is not available anymore after the first release on the App Store ?

Comment: This answer is mainly toward the yellow alert on top, I was referring to the missing "Add new device button"

Answer (score 0):

Select your device in Xcode and click add to portal.