# How can I register iPad devices (for testers) if the "Add new device" button is missing?

Tags: ios, ipad, udid

The "manage devices" page ( https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action ) doesn't have the "Add new device" button. Do you know why and what can I do?

Thanks.

PS: this (unanswered) question deals with the same problem: [Add Devices to Provisionning Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561214/add-devices-to-provisionning-profile)

Answer (score 1):

either the user you are logging-in is not a admin user and this user does not have rights to add device or you have exhausted your limit of adding 100 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Safari? I've had problems that other web browsers sometimes look like they're working, but they don't. Obviously, I assume you have not used up your max 100 devices and that you have all of your required certificates.

Comment: Safari and Firefox. Same problem. I believe that the magic 100 was reached. But what annoys me is that the interface doesn't tell me so. It just hides the button.